# dlopen in libc and libdl

Tags: linux, dynamic, linker, libc

If a gcc-compiled program is calling dlopen, it has to be compiled with the -ldl option enabled. This means that such a program relies at run time on the library libdl.so. In fact by doing ldd on it we see the line:

```
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
```

libc.so in turn uses dlopen (e.g., to deal with libnss.so), but doing ldd on  libldl.so doesn't appear:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5a488e4000)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7bdfe000)
```

Why this difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`libdl` is only exposing the **private** dl functions that already exist in libc as well as some wrappers to make the use of the libraries a bit easier. You can see some of this behaviour by looking at the symbol table of `libdl`.

If you use readelf on `libdl`, limiting to PRIVATE symbols:

```
readelf -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so | grep PRIVATE
    13: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _rtld_global_ro@GLIBC_PRIVATE (7)
    14: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _dl_vsym@GLIBC_PRIVATE (8)
    16: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _dl_addr@GLIBC_PRIVATE (8)
    18: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _dl_sym@GLIBC_PRIVATE (8)
    20: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _dl_rtld_di_serinfo@GLIBC_PRIVATE (7)
    25: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _rtld_global@GLIBC_PRIVATE (7)
    34: 00000000002030c0     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   27 _dlfcn_hook@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
    39: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

You see all the entries that are `UND`, listing from GLIBC_PRIVATE? those are all referencing the implementations within libc.

The defined API of libc itself is not declared as implementing the `dl` functions as an exposed API, however in `glibc` libdl is tightly bound to `libc`, and it exposes the known API. glibc can use the private routines within itself to accomplish the run-time opening and using of the relevant `.so` files for `nss` routines in this case.